# analog audio output card not seen. audio card bcm2835 ALSA

Tags: sound

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and my monitor has no speakers and the audio won't play out of the headphones I have connected I've tried pulse audio and sound settings. I'm not sure my audio card is being seen.

**System settings** shows:
bcm2835 ALSA
1 output/1 input
Analog Audio Output

Output tab and pulse only show HDMI output

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting here is a trouble shooting guide that might help

Answer (score 0):

In system settings, open multimedia.
select audio devices, and output.
set output device to default audio.

sometimes in pulse audio controls,
you also have to set headphone, though is should automatically switch.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61819/discussion-on-answer-by-ravery-analog-audio-output-card-not-seen-audio-card-bcm).